# Delete key sometimes doesn't work in HTML Editor of Nodeclipse NTS (Based on Eclipse 4.3 Kepler)

Tags: eclipse, html-editor, eclipse-kepler, nodeclipse

I noticed that Delete key sometimes doesn't work in HTML Editor of [Nodeclipse NTS](http://www.nodeclipse.org/nts/) ([Based on Eclipse 4.3 Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)).

Is it only in my installation / my PC (I use Eclipse on Window 7)?

Also I can't save file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or via clicking disket on menu bar. Only through save all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

UPDATE: The bug was only one day, can't reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was only on Windows 32 bit in Nodeclispe NTS 0.4.14 based on IDE for Java EE developers.
Possible reason could be that Windows hibernating causes some memory leaks.